# Can I write a script that will automatically switch users?

Tags: windows, script, windows-server-2008

I want to be able to run a script (or hit a hotkey that runs a script) that automatically switches from the currently logged on user to another logged on user. Is it possible to do such a thing? I'm using Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition. If I need to switch quickly between users, it's annoying to have to hit <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, then "Switch User," then the user account you want to switch to. Double-clicking a batch file or running a some kind of powershell command would be much more convenient. Thanks!

Comment: I think this may actually be better suited to Stack Overflow, or even Server Fault.

Comment: jerrjyl: I've talked with Jeff about these types of questions and scripting such as this is probably most suitable for SuperUser. If it was something more in depth and SysAdmin-related than just switching user accounts, it probably would have moved to ServerFault. As it stands now the question will stay here.

Comment: TheTXI: might be worth adding something about this to the main FAQ page to avoid a lot of needless reporting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this post](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2008/01/17/shortcut-to-switch-user-in-windows-vista/) - it looks like it would work in Server 2008 as well.

Comment: Not bad! I can't specify a particular user to automatically switch to, but at least this bypasses having to click the "Switch User" button. Once I get 15 rep, I'll upvote :)